# Why 1534236469 can't pass

Tags: java

I think 1534236469 out of range! Leetcode: 7. Reverse Integer
I can't pass the test input 1534236469. why? the return range is[Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE],others should return zero

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        if(x > Integer.MAX_VALUE || x < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            return 0;
        int ans = 0;
        while(x != 0) {
            ans = ans * 10 + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you know the value that's failing, have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger? What value does it return? What value would you expect it to return? Have you looked at the range of `int`? Are you able to use `long` instead?

Comment: What is the exact input, what is the expected output (and why) and what is the current output?

Comment: Input is 1534236469, expected output is 0, and current output is 1056389759

Comment: Read the question again: "return range", but you're checking the input range which (obviously) cannot exceed it's own limits.

Comment: yes,you are right

Answer (score 8):

The reverse of `1534236469` is `9646324351`, which is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so your code will result in numeric overflow and an incorrect result.

You can use `long` instead of `int` to fix the problem.

EDIT:

Your added `if(x > Integer.MAX_VALUE || x < Integer.MIN_VALUE)` condition is pointless, since `x` is `int`, so it will never be outside the valid range of `int`s.

Even if `x` is within the valid range, the reverse of `x` may be outside the range. If you want to detect that the reversed `x` is too large and return 0, you should use `long` internally:

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        long ans = 0;
        while(x != 0) {
            ans = ans * 10 + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        }
        if(ans > Integer.MAX_VALUE || ans < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (int) ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question asked me to return int...

Comment: @Clown.chen It's not possible to return an `int` if you are supposed to reverse the number 1534236469 successfully.

Comment: sorry,this is first time I use stackoverflow,I forget to say the range,I understand your meaning. thank you!

Comment: @Clown.chen see edit

Comment: You forget the situation that the input is a nagative number

Comment: @Clown.chen How are you supposed to reverse a negative number? Are you reversing the digits and keeping the sign?