# Incorrect result of power calculation when base is greater than 8

Tags: java

My code to get the power of any base with exponent 10 runs okay from 1 to 8: after that the result isn't correct. What did I miss?
Please check if the base is 9 or 10?

```
public static int power(int base, int exponent){
    int powResult = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        powResult = powResult * base;
    }
    return powResult;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Enter your x number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = input.nextInt();
    
    int v1 = power(x, 10);
    
    int result = v1;
    
    System.out.println("your input : "+ x);
    System.out.print("your result : "+ result);
```

| Input | Expected output | Printed output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 282475249 | 282475249 |
| 8 | 1073741824 | 1073741824 |
| 9 | 3486784401 | -808182895 |
| 10 | 10000000000 | 1410065408 |

Comment: Can you give an example of an incorrect output that this code is giving?

Comment: Not that I see any object-oriented programming here. But it’s Java alright.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why 1534236469 can't pass \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029809/why-1534236469-cant-pass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the datatype 'int' just can contain values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.
So when you assign to the int type 'powResult' a higher value it breaks. Try to define your powResult as a long.

Comment: "Remember that the datatype 'int' just can contain values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647": it really depends on the compiler. Some ints are 16 bits, some are 64 bits. But in that very case, you're right. But defining as a `long` may not solve the issue either. `long` may be 32 bit too. Using `long long` would be a safer bet

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Wrong. **All** Java `int`s are exactly 32 bits, it’s in the JLS. (Were you thinking C?)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `int` which my guess is represented internally as a signed 2^32 value. So in effect the largest value it can represent is `2147483648`

9^10 is 3486784401